# drupal sum up int fields in user profile

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

In my user profile I have some INT fields which represent quantity that the members will order on next delivery.

Using views I can create a nice looking table, but I also want to sum up these fields so that I can see the total amount of the product that I need to deliver that month.

I have been told that views will not accomplish this, so how would a drupal expert approach the issue?

Comment: It depends...are your fields attached to the user entity itself or to a profile using the profile2 module?

Comment: user entity, not using a plugin only drupal core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use views custom fields, add this field at last int he views. You can write php cpde over here and you get all the fields that you previously added in this view over here.

Drupal 7 has views_php in replacement to views_customfield in drupal6.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you for your time. Do you mean to use the dev-stage-module called views_php? Or is there a way to put php code into the views processing with something like a file called views_php.php?
I understand the concept you are explaining, just not how to actually do it, how/where do I add this custom field and how do I put data into it for each iteration in the views-loop or however it works underneath the hood...

Comment: There exists a module called views_php. This provides you with the functionality to put in a php code field into views. 

Now, add the php code to sum up the fields you want. Also views provide you to access other fields(that you might be needing to sum up).

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

The [Views Calc](http://drupal.org/project/views_calc) module does just what you're looking for, but it doesn't yet have a recommended release for Drupal 7. Still, it might be worth trying the [7.x-1.x-dev release](http://drupal.org/node/1071490), just in case.